# How to set java ParagraphView foreground

Tags: java, foreground

As in the title, how do I set foreground for javax.swing.text.ParagraphView, background is ok. I am using this in a JTextPane. Thanks.

Comment: What problem are you encountering? Can you show post the related code?

Comment: i am setting a JTextPane to render text in a paragraph so that it can auto wrap.